# Default parameter values via semantics in GLSL

Tags: glsl, shader, cg

I know little to nothing about the actual writing of shaders although I have a basic understanding of their place in the rendering pipeline.  I have a CG shader that I have aquired from [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=CelShading.cg) and [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=VertEdge.cg).  I am attempting to convert these shaders to GLSL.  I have gone through the reference docs and found the languages to be very similar and converted all the bits that were obvious based on the methods and syntax available.  I am having some issues with default values on parameters however.  Based on [this webpage](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_chapter03.html) the line:

```
float4 iPos     : POSITION,
```

, means it is setting the default value via a "Semantic".  This is where I am starting to get lost.  The same thing doesn't appear to be available in GLSL unless I am missing something.  I don't understand what the closest parallel is in GLSL or what it means for the conversion effort.  How do I properly account for this when converting the shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cg semantics are a way to alias attributes and varyings with certain built-in fixed-function attributes and varyings. A Cg attribute is first and foremost just a generic vertex attribute without any semantic. But in OpenGL (well, only in old and deprecated OpenGL) you have certain fixed-function attributes that carry, well, a semantic. E.g. the vertex position is set with `glVertex` or `glVertexPointer`, while a vertex's normal is set with `glNormal` or `glNormalPointer`. By giving a previously plain generic attribute the semantic `POSITION` or `NORMAL` in Cg, you can make it source it's values from such a fixed-function attribute channel.

In GLSL there are in turn built-in vertex attribute variables that contain the values of the deprecated fixed-function attributes, e.g. `gl_Vertex`, `gl_Normal`, ... for the position, normal and other semantics. But like said those fixed-function attribute channels are actually deprecated and their use in modern OpenGL is discouraged (or even prohibited in a core profile). What you should instead use is the generic vertex attributes, set with `glVertexAttrib` and `glVertexAttribPointer`. Those don't carry an actual semantic and only get their semantic by the shader using them in a particular way. But if you need to port an older application over from Cg to GLSL, then using the deprecated builtin attributes like `gl_Vertex` or `gl_Normal` and the like is the best subsitute for Cg's attribute semantics like `POSITION` or `NORMAL`.

In the same way there are certain varyings that carry a special meaning and need to be treated specially, like the clip-space position (semantic `POSITION`?). Those correspond to special varying variables you can write to in the vertex shader, like `gl_Position` in this case. And in deprecated OpenGL there are also other varying variables that can be written to and that correspond to certain fixed-function varyings, like `gl_TexCoord[i]` and the `TEXCOORDi` semantic. When using those you can easily interface shaders with fixed-function stages and e.g. use a vertex shader but fixed-function fragment processing.

So to sum up those Cg semantics actually correspond to special pre-defined attribute and varying variables in GLSL. But in modern OpenGL all of those special vertex attributes and most of those special varying variables don't exist anymore. But I advise you to first delve a little deeper into how GLSL and Cg works in practice, since as you see porting between those two is not as simple as subsitituting some keywords.